# How do you check whether a python method is bound or not?

Tags: python, python-datamodel

Given a reference to a method, is there a way to check whether the method is bound to an object or not?  Can you also access the instance that it's bound to?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```py
def isbound(method):
    return method.im_self is not None
    
def instance(bounded_method):
    return bounded_method.im_self
```

[User-defined methods:](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#index-40)

> When a user-defined method object is
> created by retrieving a user-defined
> function object from a class, its
> `im_self` attribute is `None` and the
> method object is said to be unbound.
> When one is created by retrieving a
> user-defined function object from a
> class via one of its instances, its
> `im_self` attribute is the instance, and
> the method object is said to be bound.
> In either case, the new method's
> `im_class` attribute is the class from
> which the retrieval takes place, and
> its `im_func` attribute is the original
> function object.

In Python [2.6 and 3.0](https://docs.python.org/2.7/whatsnew/2.6.html):

> Instance method objects have new
> attributes for the object and function
> comprising the method; the new synonym
> for `im_self` is `__self__`, and `im_func`
> is also available as `__func__`. The old
> names are still supported in Python
> 2.6, but are gone in 3.0.

Answer (score 28):

In python 3 the `__self__` attribute is *only* set on bound methods. It's not set to `None` on plain functions (or unbound methods, which are just plain functions in python 3).

Use something like this:

```
def is_bound(m):
    return hasattr(m, '__self__')
```

Comment: There are plain functions that have the `__self__` attribute set, e.g. the built-in function `sum`.

Answer (score 15):

The chosen answer is valid in almost all cases. However when checking if a method is bound in a decorator using chosen answer, the check will fail. Consider this example decorator and method:

```
def my_decorator(*decorator_args, **decorator_kwargs):
    def decorate(f):
        print(hasattr(f, '__self__'))
        @wraps(f)
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrap
    return decorate

class test_class(object):
    @my_decorator()
    def test_method(self, *some_params):
        pass
```

The `print` statement in decorator will print `False`.
In this case I can't find any other way but to check function parameters using their argument names and look for one named `self`. This is also **not** guarantied to work flawlessly because the first argument of a method is not forced to be named `self` and can have any other name.

```
import inspect

def is_bounded(function):
    params = inspect.signature(function).parameters
    return params.get('self', None) is not None
```

Comment: Well `f` is never actually bound to `test_class` which is the complication here. Even `decorate` is not bound either (you can verify by checking test_class.test_method != decorate). A bound method is created from `decorate` and *that* is what is attached to `test_class`. What you are really trying to find is whether a bound method has been created from a specific function. I'm not sure if that is possible

Comment: I think this is the only way to know if the given function expects to receive the insance or or not.

Comment: import inspect; expectself = next(iter(inspect.signature(function))) == 'self'

Comment: I agree that this is impossible. I've attempted through [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25959545/308451) and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54316392/308451). The latter _almost_ works, until a second (unrelated) decorator is added before your decorator. The next best thing I can come up with truly is simply checking for `"self"` (and/or `"cls"`)...

Comment: What happens here is that functions in classes are normal, unbound. When creating an instance (when ``__new__`` is called), bound methods are created for those functions and populate new instance. So, there is no way that a normal function in class is bound, because it isn't and decorators are "applied" just after function creation (and therefore before class creation), so there isn't even any object that such function could be applied to. ``@classmethod`` uses a trick named "```__get__``` magic method".

Answer (score 5):

[`im_self` attribute](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=im_self) (only Python 2)

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works for both Python 2 and 3 is tricky.

Using the package [`six`](https://six.readthedocs.io/), one solution could be:

```py
def is_bound_method(f):
    """Whether f is a bound method"""
    try:
        return six.get_method_self(f) is not None
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

In Python 2:

- A regular function won't have the `im_self` attribute so `six.get_method_self()` will raise an `AttributeError` and this will return `False`
- An unbound method will have the `im_self` attribute set to `None` so this will return `False`
- An bound method will have the `im_self` attribute set to non-`None` so this will return `True`

In Python 3:

- A regular function won't have the `__self__` attribute so `six.get_method_self()` will raise an `AttributeError` and this will return `False`
- An unbound method is the same as a regular function so this will return `False`
- An bound method will have the `__self__` attribute set (to non-`None`) so this will return `True`