# Decorator which skips `self` for methods

Tags: python

Let's say we have multiple functions which all accept an URL as their first argument and this URL needs to be validated. This can be nicely solved with a decorator

```
def validate_url(f):
   def validated(url, *args, **kwargs):
       assert len(url.split('.')) == 3 # trivial example
       return f(url, *args, **kwargs)
    return validated

@validate_url
def some_func(url, some_other_arg, *some_args, **some_kwargs):
    pass
```

This approach will work and allow me to factor the validation behavior out of many instances of similar functions. But now I would want to write a class method which also takes a validated URL. However, the naive approach will not work

```
class SomeClass:
    @validate_url
    def some_method(self, url, some_other_args):
        pass
```

because we will end up attempting to validate `self` and not `url`. My question is how to write a single decorator which will work for both functions and methods with the minimum amount of boilerplate.

Note 1: I am aware *why* this happens, it's just that I don't know how to work around this in the most elegant manner.

Note 2: The URL validation problem is just an example, so checking if `isinstance(args[0], str)` is not a good solution.

Comment: Not sure whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53322/6699447) can be applied here

Comment: Could you define a `@staticmethod` like `def validate_url(url, *args)` that runs inside of `some_func`? You could then decorate `validate_url`. Seems hacky and non-Pythonic, but that's the first thing I'd try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to somehow detect whether the decorated function is a class method or not — which seems to be difficult if not impossible (as far as I can tell anyway) to do so cleanly. The `inspect` module's `ismethod()` and `isfunction()` don't work inside a decorator used inside a class definition.

Given that, here's a somewhat hacky way of doing it which checks to see if the decorated callable's first argument has been given the name `"self"`, which is the coding convention for it in class methods (although it is **not a requirement**, so [caveat emptor](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/caveat-emptor) and use at your own risk).

The following code seems to work in both Python 2 and 3. However in Python 3 it may raise `DeprecationWarning`s depending on exactly what sub-version is being used—so they have been suppressed in a section of the code below.

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect
import warnings

def validate_url(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def validated(*args, **kwargs):
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            # Suppress DeprecationWarnings in this section.
            warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)

            # If "f"'s first argument is named "self",
            # assume it's a method.
            if inspect.getargspec(f).args[0] == 'self':
                url = args[1]
            else:  # Otherwise assume "f" is a ordinary function.
                url = args[0]
        print('testing url: {!r}'.format(url))
        assert len(url.split('.')) == 3  # Trivial "validation".
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return validated

@validate_url
def some_func(url, some_other_arg, *some_args, **some_kwargs):
    print('some_func() called')


class SomeClass:
    @validate_url
    def some_method(self, url, some_other_args):
        print('some_method() called')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('** Testing decorated function **')
    some_func('xxx.yyy.zzz', 'another arg')
    print('  URL OK')
    try:
        some_func('https://bogus_url.com', 'another thing')
    except AssertionError:
        print('  INVALID URL!')

    print('\n** Testing decorated method **')
    instance = SomeClass()
    instance.some_method('aaa.bbb.ccc', 'something else')  # -> AssertionError
    print('  URL OK')
    try:
        instance.some_method('foo.bar', 'arg 2')  # -> AssertionError
    except AssertionError:
        print('  INVALID URL!')
```

Output:

```
** Testing decorated function **
testing url: 'xxx.yyy.zzz'
some_func() called
  URL OK
testing url: 'https://bogus_url.com'
  INVALID URL!

** Testing decorated method **
testing url: 'aaa.bbb.ccc'
some_method() called
  URL OK
testing url: 'foo.bar'
  INVALID URL!
```